# sha512 in Solidity or assembly, does it exist?

Tags: keccak, sha3, hash-algorithm

Is it possible to do sha512 within a smart contract? Or, not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smart Pool has an implementation of sha3_512,
https://github.com/SmartPool/contracts/blob/develop/contracts/Ethash.sol

If that could be turned into a stand-alone library, with a bit of documentation, then Ethereum would have on-state sha512.